# Hibernate HyperSQL - JDBCExceptionReporter [WARN] no data

Tags: sql, hibernate

I'm trying to use Hibernate with HyperSQL in a web application.

Here is my log when server start.

```
2012-11-27 09:59:46 SessionFactoryImpl [INFO] building session factory
2012-11-27 09:59:46 SessionFactoryObjectFactory [INFO] Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
2012-11-27 09:59:46 SchemaExport [INFO] Running hbm2ddl schema export
2012-11-27 09:59:46 SchemaExport [INFO] exporting generated schema to database
2012-11-27 09:59:46 SchemaExport [INFO] Executing import script: /import.sql
2012-11-27 09:59:46 SchemaExport [INFO] schema export complete
2012-11-27 09:59:46 JDBCExceptionReporter [WARN] SQL Warning: -1100, SQLState: 02000
2012-11-27 09:59:46 JDBCExceptionReporter [WARN] no data
```

I import the tables and data with import.sql automatically.
I create/drop the table and create/delete the data with hibernate when the server start/stop.

Although this web application works fine, I am still curious about what is the warning mean in the server start log.

Can someone explain following warning log for me?

```
2012-11-27 09:59:46 JDBCExceptionReporter [WARN] SQL Warning: -1100, SQLState: 02000
2012-11-27 09:59:46 JDBCExceptionReporter [WARN] no data
```

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer, but I just encountered this problem too.  The problem was related to deleting the table from inside a transaction

The way I avoided these warnings was to change my command to:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE <table> RESTART IDENTITY AND COMMIT
```

The `AND COMMIT` commits the truncation immediately.  This made the error go away.